# Click Event of Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How to find Whether a hyperlink is clicked or not in ASP.net C# in runtime? 
I want to write code on like that

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Comment: if clicked... it will go to `NavigateUrl` specified url... what do you really want to do?

Comment: In run time I changed Text of Hyperlink now if to that changed Text is clicked I want to Redirect to other Page !

Comment: Now, you didn't make any sense :) can you rephrase it plz?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to execute server code upon a click in a link, then you should use the ASP.NET control `<asp:LinkButton>`

This is just like a button and will allow you to hook up Server Side Events and at the end you can just redirect the viewer to any page.

Answer (score 10):

You would attach either the event in the code behind, or in the ASPX / ASCX of your link in question like so:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="linkGoSomewhere" runat="server" Click="linkGoSomewhere_Click" />
```

OR

```
 linkGoSomewhere.Click += (linkGoSomewhere_Click);
```

With an event handler looking like so in your code:

```
 public void linkGoSomewhere_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
 }
```

**HOWEVER**

In this situation, you don't need a server side control to just send the user somewhere else. You just need a simple hyperlink:

```
 <a href="Default.aspx">Go somewhere else</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

if this HyperLink you can do it using javascript but if it is `LinkButton` you can do it inside `onclick` event

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLnkButton" runat="server" onClick="MyLnkButton_Click" Text="Click Me!">

protected void MyLnkButton_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The onclick server side handler can be added to achieve this.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEditLine" runat="server" Text="Edit" onclick="lnkEdit_Click"/>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine this with the `Click` event of the LinkButton