# in asp.net, how do i take a textbox value from my page and pass it as a value to the navigate url of the <asp:HyperLink>

Tags: asp.net

New to this...and nothing seems to work.

Here's part of the page.

```
    <asp:HyperLink id="lblParentUser" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/admin-users.aspx?userid=<%txtParentUserId.Text%>"></asp:HyperLink>
    <%--<asp:HyperLink id="lblParentUser" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("txtParentUserId","~/admin-users.aspx?userid={0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>--%>             


  <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtParentUserId" Enabled="false" style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS','Tahoma'; font-size: 18px; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; border-color: #c1c1c1; width: 370px;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# MyURL()%>'
```

in code behind:

```
   public String MyUrl()
    { return "your value";}
```

Comment: added                <asp:HyperLink id="lblParentUser" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# GetTheUrl()%>'></asp:HyperLink>

Comment: Function GetTheUrl() As String
        Return "~/admin-users.aspx?userid=" + parentUserId.ToString
    End Function

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1. Use [LinkButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7231714/900284)
2. Use [__doPostBack function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/__doPostBack-function)

```
/// Html sample
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ClickNRedirect(parameter) {
                __doPostBack('lblParentUser', parameter); 
            }
        </script>            
        <asp:HyperLink id="lblParentUser" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#" onclick="javascript:ClickNRedirect('It is optional');" >click here</asp:HyperLink>            
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>            
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" 
            id="txtParentUserId" 
            Enabled="false">
        </asp:TextBox>                
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

/// C# Code behind  Sample
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack){
        string ControlName = Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // For Control Name, For more detail http://goo.gl/7Uw9ka
        string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // For Parameter , it is optional.
        if (ControlName.Equals("lblParentUser"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/admin-users.aspx?userid={0}", txtParentUserId.Text), false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If txtParentUserId is part of a form post, then you can simply write the HTML for the link during the postback.

```
 <%
  Response.Write(String.Format("
  <a href='/../admin-users.aspx?userid={0}'/>click here</a>",
   txtParentUserId.Text.ToString()));
 %>
```

If the txtParentUserId is set (or could be set) during initial page load (IsPostBack==false), then you will need to set the value in either the code-behind (sometime after txtParentUserId.Text is set)....

```
 HyperLink link = (HyperLink)lblParentUser;
 TextBox txt = (TextBox)txtParentUserId;
 link.NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/admin-users.aspx?userid={0}",txt.Text.ToString());
```

Or on the client using javascript...

```
 <script lang="javascript">
  var url = "/../admin2-users.aspx?userid=" +
      document.getElementById("txtParentUserId").value;
  document.getElementById("lblParentUser").href = url;

 </script>
```

For the last example, make sure ClientID property is the same as the ID property and that the CliendIDMode is set to Static. For example..

```
  <asp:HyperLink ID="lblParentUser" ClientID="lblParentUser" ClientIDMode="Static" ...

  <asp:TextBox ID="txtParentUserId" ClientID="txtParentUserId" ClientIDMode="Static"...
```

Comment: I used:    If the txtParentUserId is set (or could be set) during initial page load (IsPostBack==false), then you will need to set the value in either the code-behind (sometime after txtParentUserId.Text is set)....

and it worked. The javascript option did not work.

Comment: I modified it to be:   <script lang="javascript">
  var url = "~/admin-users.aspx?userid=" +
      document.getElementById("txtParentUserId").value;
  document.getElementById("lblParentUser").NavigateURL = url;

 </script>

Comment: <asp:HyperLink id="lblParentUser" runat="server" ClientID="lblParentUser" ClientIDMode="Static" NavigateUrl="set by javascript"></asp:HyperLink>

Comment: The URL returned was not the correct path and the userid was "set by javascript" not the id I expected.

Comment: @user3020047 The asp:HyperLink control is a ASP.Net server-side only control. Therefore, the NavigateUrl attribute will not be accessible on the browser. However, the HyperLink control is sent to the browser as an anchor tag (i.e. "<a...></a>"). So, to modify the URL for that link you must do so by setting the href attribute.